# MS Access | Find Top Combinations

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have searched google/stack to find the right answer, but what I have tried so far is not working.

Here is the problem:

I have created a table with several combinations. I am trying to find the combination that minimizes total cost.

As an example, the table looks something like this:

```
Combo ID | Combination | Cost
1 | 345678 | 15
2 | 345678 | 15
3 | 345678 | 18
4 | 456343 | 12
5 | 456343 | 13
```

So: for the combination `345678`, ID #1 and #2 both minimize the cost and #4 minimizes the cost for the `456343` combination. So hopefully the query can return either the IDs `1,2,4` or it can simply return the total cost that is the minimum for that combination eg `{ (345678, 15), (456343, 12) }`

Comment: simple `select Combination, min(Cost) from table group by Combination` should work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the IDs, you have to have a sub query that first gets the Min cost.  Then you can match the combination and cost to the original Table.

SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Combo, Table1.Cost
FROM Query1 INNER JOIN Table1 ON (Query1.MinOfCost = Table1.Cost) AND (Query1.Combo = Table1.Combo)

Query 1 :SELECT Table1.Combo, Min(Table1.Cost) AS MinOfCost FROM Table1 GROUP BY Table1.Combo